# ORA-12703: this character set conversion is not supported

Tags: oracle, email, plsql

I am encountering an Conversion error message when running the below code:

```
Declare
v_t MyType;
assignment_param        NVARCHAR2(10);
project_name_param      NVARCHAR2(100);
document_nick_name_param    NVARCHAR2(100);
doc_created_by          NVARCHAR2(100);
id              NVARCHAR2(10);
project_launch_date     NVARCHAR2(100);
assignment_type_param   NVARCHAR2(100);
temp                    NVARCHAR2(30000);
Begin
        assignment_param := get_assignment_type(f_id);
        project_name_param := get_project_name(f_id);
        document_nick_name_param := get_document_nick_name(f_id);
        doc_created_by := get_doc_created_by(f_id);
        id := get_id(f_id);
        project_launch_date := get_project_launch_date(f_id);
        IF (assignment_param = 'manual') THEN
            assignment_type_param := 'manually';
        ELSE
             assignment_type_param := 'automatically';
        END IF;
        v_t := MyType();
        v_t.EXTEND(7);
        v_t(1) := 'assignment_param='||assignment_param;
        v_t(2) := 'project_name_param='||project_name_param;
        v_t(3) := 'document_nick_name_param='||document_nick_name_param;
        v_t(4) := 'doc_created_by='||doc_created_by;
        v_t(5) := 'id='||id;
        v_t(6) := 'project_launch_date='||project_launch_date;
        v_t(7) := 'assignment_type_param='||assignment_type_param;
        temp := Replace_Email_Body_Contents(12,v_t);
End;
```

Also my other function has code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Replace_Email_Body_Contents
(
    id_inparam IN NUMBER,
    replace_var_loop IN MyType
)
RETURN NVARCHAR2
AS
    db_string NVARCHAR2(10000);
    str_1 NVARCHAR2(100);
    str_2 NVARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    --loading the email template from html string column of form_templates_data table;
    SELECT HTML_STRING INTO db_string FROM TABLE WHERE ID = id_inparam;

    FOR i IN 1..replace_var_loop.COUNT LOOP           
      SELECT SUBSTR(replace_var_loop(i), 0, INSTR(replace_var_loop(i), '=')-1) INTO str_1  FROM DUAL;
      SELECT SUBSTR(replace_var_loop(i),  INSTR(replace_var_loop(i), '=')+1) INTO str_2 FROM DUAL;

      db_string := REPLACE(db_string , str_1 , str_2 );

    END LOOP;
    dbms_output.put_line(db_string);

      RETURN db_string;
END;
/
```

Error:

> ORA-12703: this character set conversion is not supported
>   ORA-06512: at "REPLACE_EMAIL_BODY_CONTENTS", line 13
>   ORA-06512: at line 32

HTML_STRING is a column in the table referred in above code and the values corresponding to f_id looks like:

Notification
Hello,

You have been assignment_param-assigned a document.

**Project Name:** project_name_param

**Document Nickname:**  document_nick_name_param

**Doc Created By:**  doc_created_by

 
**LCA ID:**  lca_id

**Project Launch Date:**  project_launch_date

Based on the evaluation of the checklist, an Engineer has been assignment_type_param assigned to work with the project team.

Comment: What is the definition of "mytype"?

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MYTYPE AS VARRAY (200) OF VARCHAR2 (10000);

Comment: Please run this query and append it's results do the question: `select * from nls_database_parameters
where parameter like '%CHARACTERSET%'`. The query retrieves settings related to encodings used in your database.

Comment: Parameter  Value
NLS_CHARACTERSET WE8ISO8859P1
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16

Comment: What type is HTML_STRING is it VARCHAR , NVARCHAR, BLOB, CLOB?

Comment: I got it fixed. HTML_STRING was VARCHAR2 and temp (in my email function) was set as NVARCHAR2. I changed the data type for temp to VARCHAR2 and fixed the code. Didn't know VARCHAR2 adn NVARCHAR2 would impact it. I thought they both means almost same thing.